# Having clause satisfying 2 conditions in date

Tags: sql, sql-server, having

I have a `having` clause that returns all payments that are more than 5 days old. It essentially says if a payment is 5 or more days old and is of type 1 then show it. I now want it with if a payment is more than 5 days old for types 0 and 1 then show it. Both types 0 and 1 will have the a customer name that they will share so what I am trying to do is this

- Customer A type 0 payment is 7 days old and type 1 payment is 2 days old then **don't show**
- Customer B type 0 payment is 6 days old and type 1 payment is 8 days old then **show**

Code:

```
select distinct MAX(paymentDate) as payment, type, customer
group by payment
having datediff(day, MAX(paymentDate), getdate()) > 5 and type = 1
```

Any suggestions would be great. We also need to have the `Max` aggregate in the clause since we only want the latest payment date for the customer and type .

Comment: could you explain a bit more what you except as the output ? maybe a [mcve]

Comment: `HAVING` should **only** be applied to **aggregated columns**, e.g. `HAVING COUNT(...) > 5` or something like that. If you have **non-aggregated columns** - like here in your case - use just a regular, simple `WHERE` clause instead

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
select p.*
from payments p
where type = 1 and
      paymentDate < dateadd(day, -5, convert(date, getdate()));
```

I don't see why aggregation would be used here.